# Implementation of a graph with adjacency list in C

Tags: c, graph, adjacency-list

I read a code implementing a graph with adjacency list. But I am so
 confused about the addEdge function.

In the function of the following code, when the newNode->next is assigned 
 with array[src].head. That means the next node of newNode is
 array[src].head. But after the statement"graph->array[src].head = newNode;", the order is the other way around as we test the result. Can someone explain to me? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 

// A structure to represent an adjacency list node 
struct AdjListNode 
{ 
    int dest; 
    struct AdjListNode* next; 
}; 

// A structure to represent an adjacency list 
struct AdjList 
{ 
    struct AdjListNode *head;  
}; 

// A structure to represent a graph. A graph 
// is an array of adjacency lists. 
// Size of array will be V (number of vertices  
// in graph) 
struct Graph 
{ 
    int V; 
    struct AdjList* array; 
}; 

// A utility function to create a new adjacency list node 
struct AdjListNode* newAdjListNode(int dest) 
{ 
    struct AdjListNode* newNode = 
     (struct AdjListNode*) malloc(sizeof(struct AdjListNode)); 
    newNode->dest = dest; 
    newNode->next = NULL; 
    return newNode; 
} 

// A utility function that creates a graph of V vertices 
struct Graph* createGraph(int V) 
{ 
    struct Graph* graph =  
        (struct Graph*) malloc(sizeof(struct Graph)); 
    graph->V = V; 

    // Create an array of adjacency lists.  Size of  
    // array will be V 
    graph->array =  
      (struct AdjList*) malloc(V * sizeof(struct AdjList)); 

    // Initialize each adjacency list as empty by  
    // making head as NULL 
    int i; 
    for (i = 0; i < V; ++i) 
        graph->array[i].head = NULL; 

    return graph; 
} 

// Adds an edge to an undirected graph 
void addEdge(struct Graph* graph, int src, int dest) 
{ 
    // Add an edge from src to dest.  A new node is  
    // added to the adjacency list of src.  The node 
    // is added at the begining 
    struct AdjListNode* newNode = newAdjListNode(dest); 
    newNode->next = graph->array[src].head; 
    graph->array[src].head = newNode; 

    // Since graph is undirected, add an edge from 
    // dest to src also 
    newNode = newAdjListNode(src); 
    newNode->next = graph->array[dest].head; 
    graph->array[dest].head = newNode; 
} 

// A utility function to print the adjacency list  
// representation of graph 
void printGraph(struct Graph* graph) 
{ 
    int v; 
    for (v = 0; v < graph->V; ++v) 
    { 
        struct AdjListNode* pCrawl = graph->array[v].head; 
        printf("\n Adjacency list of vertex %d\n head ", v); 
        while (pCrawl) 
        { 
            printf("-> %d", pCrawl->dest); 
            pCrawl = pCrawl->next; 
        } 
        printf("\n"); 
    } 
} 

// Driver program to test above functions 
int main() 
{ 
    // create the graph given in above fugure 
    int V = 5; 
    struct Graph* graph = createGraph(V); 
    addEdge(graph, 0, 1); 
    addEdge(graph, 0, 4); 
    addEdge(graph, 1, 2); 
    addEdge(graph, 1, 3); 
    addEdge(graph, 1, 4); 
    addEdge(graph, 2, 3); 
    addEdge(graph, 3, 4); 

    // print the adjacency list representation of the above graph 
    printGraph(graph); 

    return 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> In the function of the following code, when the `newNode->next` is
>   assigned  with `array[src].head`. That means the `next` node of
>   `newNode` is `array[src].head`.  But after the statement
>   `graph->array[src].head = newNode;`, the order is the other way around
>   as we test the result. Can someone explain to me? Thanks!

This is correct.  The function `addEdge` is inserting the new node at the beginning of the list, as you have confirmed from your test output.

This line:

```
newNode->next = graph->array[dest].head;
```

makes the new node's `next` pointer point to the beginning of the current list (before the list is updated).

Then this line:

```
graph->array[dest].head = newNode;
```

updates the beginning of the list to point to the new node you just added.

Now the list looks like:

```
[head == new-node] -> [... state of list before addEdge was called ...]
```

Comment: Isn't head ==[new-node] rather than head-> [new-node] after graph->array[dest].head = newNode; ??

Comment: if head ==new-node, how can we link the graph->array[].head to all the nodes we add??

Comment: I don't understand your question.  All this function is doing is adding the new node to the beginning of the list, specifying an edge from src to dest.  Then adding an edge from dest to src in the similar manner.

Comment: I mean if we keep updating the head pointer, then how can we get the original pointer if we want to print the list? Because when all the edges are added, the head points are the last node in each line of the list.

Comment: When all the edges are added, the head points to the last node that was added ... which is the first node on the list.  Before there are any edges that are added for a particular src edge, there are no edges, and so the original head pointer is NULL.  I don't know why you care that the pointer changes.  All your data is on that list.  You can traverse your list (as the inner loop in `printGraph` does) to access all your data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192065/discussion-between-liu-and-mfisherkdx).

Comment: Perhaps you don't understand a [Linked List](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list). If not, then this is the root of your misunderstanding.

Comment: But for array[0].head , the output should be head->4->1 not head->1->4. Right?

Comment: Correct. Go to chat.